# Form to add data to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I'm using:

```
*connection details*

$fname = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
$surname = stripslashes($_POST['surname']);
$address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, fname, surname, address)
VALUES ('', '$fname', '$surname', '$address')";
$results = mysql_query($sql);

if ($results)
{
echo "Details added.";
}
```

the problem is an entry is added to the table but all the data is blank instead of the stuff from the form?

Form:

```
<form id="myform" action="add.php" method="post" name="myform">
<label for="fname">First Name</label> 
<input id="fname" name="fname" ><br />
<label for="surname">Surname</label> 
<input id="surname" name="surname" ><br />
<label for="address">Address</label> 
<input id="address" name="address" >
<input type="submit" name="submitButtonName" value="Add">
```

Comment: $results = mysql_query($sql);

if ($results)
{
echo "Details added.";
}

Comment: Do the _POST values actually contain any data?

Comment: can you post your html form for me? Have you done a var_dump($_POST) to make sure that the values are reaching the page as expected?

Comment: form has been edited in.

Answer (score 2):

You should post your HTML code too. Make sure the form's method is POST as:

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
   <input type="text" name="fname" />
   <input type="text" name="surname" />
   <input type="text" name="address" />
</form>
```

Also the name attributes of your `<input />` elements should be correctly set.
If this is all done you should be able to get the `$_POST` variables in the `process.php` page. Thus:

```
$fname = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
```

Check if your variables have a value by doing a simple `echo $fname;`. If they are set, a possible reason of the failing system may be your SQL query. Leave out the **id** and just do:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (firstname, surname, address)
        VALUES ('" . $fname . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $address . "')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try print this variables for debug.

```
echo $fname = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
echo $surname = stripslashes($_POST['surname']);
echo $address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
```

And you will see variables' data.

Comment: `echo $fname = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);` print nothing (as a status for variables assignment)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I would imaging that this is something small, like not having the "name" value set for your fields. If you dont have "name" set, then the post data will not contain any details. If that's not the problem, please post your code and I can see if I spot anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the id field in the data base table is auto incremented than there is no need to put that in mysql query , try this

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (fname, surname, address)
            VALUES ('$fname', '$surname', '$address')";
```